# Set formflow dialog field value without getting prompted later

Tags: botframework

I'm using `SetDefine()` to provide a value for one of  the fields on my bot dialog..

```
return builder
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(UserName))
    .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
    {
        field.SetValue(state, userName);
        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }))
```

`userName` is just a variable in the function that's calling the `return builder` line. The property `UserName` is defined as..

`public string UserName { get; set; }`

The issue I have is that, when I run the bot in the emulator, the first thing I see if this..

[image]

How can I configure the property `UserName` so that it does not get prompted for a value in the bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are defining your username field and you don't want the bot the prompt for that field you can use .SetActive

```
            .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(UserName))
            .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
            {
                field.SetValue(state, "username");
                return await Task.FromResult(true);
            })
            .SetActive((state) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.UserName)))
```

So a prompt will be only initiated if the field is Null or empty. You can try out other functions which return back a bool to match your usecase better.

Comment: You've saved the day for me again, great answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've hit a snag. Any chance you can take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097090/whats-the-correct-way-to-pass-data-when-building-a-formflow-form-from-a-root-di  please?

Comment: Happy to help. Seems like you have found a way out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that holds all of the items you want in the form. Then create a static method in that class that returns an `IForm<class>`.

```
[Serializable]
public class CallNotesForm
{
    [Prompt("What is the subject of the call?")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Prompt("What are the call details?")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public static IForm<CallNotesForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<CallNotesForm>()
                    .Message("Please enter some details about your call. Enter 'Help' for more information")
                    .Build();
    }
}
```

Then in your method that calls the form,

```
IForm<CallNotesForm> formVM = new CallNotesForm() { Direction = CallNotes.CallDirection.Outgoing };
IFormDialog<CallNotesForm> form = new FormDialog<CallNotesForm>(formVM, CallNotesForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
context.Call(form, CallDetailsAsync);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will work for me. I have a formflow dialog form which contains all the properties that are to be prompted as questions. I just need a property on that dialog to not be prompted to the user. I think creating a new form makes things more tricky.