# What's the correct way to pass data when building a formflow form from a root dialog?

Tags: botframework

I'm using a root dialog in order to create a child formflow dialog, so that I can capture exceptions, etc.

I'm encountering an issue with passing a username value to the formflow dialog. Here's what I've tried..

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        var customerForm = new FormDialog<CarValuationDialog>(
            new CarValuationDialog(),
            () => CarValuationDialog.BuildForm(context.Activity?.From.Name),
            FormOptions.PromptInStart);

        context.Call(customerForm, FormSubmitted);        
    }

    ....
}
```

The key point is

`() => CarValuationDialog.BuildForm(context.Activity?.From.Name),`

I think this is wrong, because when I run the bot I get this exception...

> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.ClosureCaptureException: 'anonymous method closures that capture the environment are not serializable, consider removing environment capture or using a reflection serialization surrogate: CarValuationBot.Dialogs.RootDialog+<>c__DisplayClass1_0'

In the formflow dialog, here is how I'm using the username value..

```
public static IForm<CarValuationDialog> BuildForm(string userName)
{
    var builder = new FormBuilder<CarValuationDialog>();

    return builder
        .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(UserName))
            .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                {
                    field.SetValue(state, userName);

                    return await Task.FromResult(true);
                })
        .SetActive(state => string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.UserName)))


        ... rest of code
}
```

Now, I did comment out the code which defines the field `UserName`, but I'm still getting the exception. That hints to me that it must be the call to `BuildForm` in the root dialog is the problem.

What is the best practise way of passing data to the formflow dialog in this scenario please?

Answer (score 1):

I fgiured out that you can set the initial state of the dialog like so

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    string userName = "Jason";
    //string userName = context.Activity?.From.Name;

    var customerForm = new FormDialog<CarValuationDialog>(
        new CarValuationDialog(userName),
        () => CarValuationDialog.BuildForm(),
        FormOptions.PromptInStart);

    context.Call(customerForm, FormSubmitted);   
}
```

The formflow dialog then stores the username via the constructor..

```
public class CarValuationDialog : IDialog<CarValuationDialog>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; 

    public CarValuationDialog(string userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
    }

   ....
}
```